# Vue: Problems with 2 components recursively calling each other

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

### Problem description

I'm writing a Vue application, where I have 2 components (`HierarchyNodesList` and `HierarchyNode`) calling each other recursively. More or less tree of components looks like this:

- HierarchyNodesList

  - HierarchyNode

    - HierarchyNodesList

      - HierarchyNode
      - HierarchyNode
      - HierarchyNode
  - HierarchyNode

    - HierarchyNodesList

      - HierarchyNode
      - HierarchyNode

For some reason I have problems to make it work. The components are rendered only up to 2nd level (root `HierarchyNodesList` and `HierarchyNode`-s nested directly in it).

In HTML tree in developer tools the 3rd level `HierarchyNodeList` appears as below. Seems it cannot be parsed in Vue template and is just left unparsed for the browser.

```
<hierarchynodeslist data-v-26be5b52="" nodes="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"></hierarchynodeslist>
```

In console those errors appear:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <HierarchyNodesList> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HierarchyNode> at src/components/HierarchyNode.vue
       <HierarchyNodesList> at src/components/HierarchyNodesList.vue
         <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
           <MainLayout> at src/layouts/MainLayout.vue
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

I registered both components in each other and provided `name` property for both (code excerpts below).

### Question

What's the cause of these problems? What is the way to fix it?

### Code

**HierarchyNodesList.vue**

```
import HierarchyNode from '@/components/HierarchyNode.vue';

export default {

  name: 'HierarchyNodesList',

  components: {
    HierarchyNode,
  },

  (...)

}
```

**HierarchyNode.vue**

```
import HierarchyNodesList from '@/components/HierarchyNodesList.vue';

export default {

  name: 'HierarchyNode',

  components: {
    HierarchyNodesList,
  },

  (...)

}
```

Comment: Maybe this? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components

Comment: @skirtle: Seems it's exactly this. Thanks. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a section in the official documentation about this kind of problem:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components

One way to fix it is global registration.

Another is to register the component in a `beforeCreate` hook:

```js
beforeCreate () {
  this.$options.components.HierarchyNodesList = require('./HierarchyNodesList.vue').default
}
```

The third is asynchronous imports:

```js
components: {
  HierarchyNodesList: () => import('./HierarchyNodesList.vue')
}
```